# Part of speech tagging using HMM: remove suffixes?

Tags: natural-language

I have implemented POS tagger using HMM. My question is do I need to filter out suffixes in it before adding it to model?
For example "running" do I need to remove "ning" then add that word to model?

Comment: the terms you want to search about are "tokenization" and "lemmatization"

Comment: @ItamarMushkin My question is should I do that in context pos tagging?

Answer (score 1):

Suffixes carry important information about the POS, there is no reason why they should be removed.

However, it might be an interesting exercise to see how much can be inferred from the presence of surrounding function words and how much information about POS is carried in the word forms.

Actually, a more meaningful vocabulary shrinking would be the opposite: keeping the most common forms untouched and replace the less with frequent words with the suffixes which are more informative than sparsely occurring stems.

Just for completeness, HMM-taggers significantly lag behind the state-of-the-art for more than a decade now. Although they are still an interesting academic exercise, in practice even very light-weight deep-learning models get much better accuracy at approximately the same computational cost.

Comment: Emission matrix would be large then. Is it normal to have 2k to 3k as row dimension?

Comment: This is perfectly fine, especially if you implement it as a sparse matrix.